# Transfer data from Android with webView to Asp.Net backend

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, kotlin

I have an Android App that is basically a webView to our asp.net web application.
Now I have to implement a barcode scanner in the Android app to read and transfer the number from the barcode to the asp.net backend.
I have this line in js in the web to call the Android function for the barcode scanner:

```
window.AndroidWebInterface.getIcc();
```

In Android I tried many different approaches to start the ScanActivity which uses ML Kit to read the barcode which is working fine, but I have problem returning the code I read with the camera to the js caller function from the backend. I can display it in the Android app but don't know how to return it to the backend.
Some code from the android app

```
barcodeScanner.process(inputImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodeList ->
                val barcode = barcodeList.getOrNull(0)
                // `rawValue` is the decoded value of the barcode
                barcode?.rawValue?.let { value ->
                    // update our textView to show the decoded value
                    binding.bottomText.text = barcode.displayValue

                    val data = Intent()
                    data.putExtra("icc", barcode.displayValue)

                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
                    finish()
                }
            }

registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        icc = result.data?.getStringExtra("icc")
    }
}

startForResult.launch(Intent(this, ScanActivity::class.java))
```

Comment: I think the instant you introduce a scanner? Then that should be driven by a webmethod call to the server. it not clear if the scanner works via keyboard wedge, but say even if you use the camera to scan the barcode? Your routine will get a barcode number returned, at that point, if you want data from server based on that barcode, then call a webmethod of the server side (ajax, or a rest call). I would not try some half baked approach in which on the phone you trying to use some web page stuck inside of a view on the phone. You already have development ability on the phone.